# Is the basis for the column space of a matrix A the same as the basis for the column space of the RREF of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused about the basis for the column space of a given matrix (let's call it A) vs. the basis for the column space of the RREF(A) (Let's call this B). If A is the original matrix and B is the reduced row echelon form of the matrix, is the basis for the column space of A equivalent to the basis for the column space of B? I think it isn't (based on a whim?) but I am not exactly sure if that is true.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What does it meant to say that two bases are equivalent?

Comment: It means to ask if they are the same. That is to ask if the basis of the column space of B the same as the basis for the column space of A.

Comment: Row-reduction does not preserve the columnspace of a matrix, so it certainly won't preserve bases (in general).